# How can I write data in a loop in Openpyxl?

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am creating a portscanner (via Python) and whenever I receive something, it should be written in an .XLSV file.

**What it should do:**

1. Webscanner finds port 21 open
2. Receives data
3. Writes it in a .XLSV file in row 2
4. Webscanner finds port 80 open
5. Receives data
6. Writes it in a .XLSV file in row 3

**My code:**

```
wb = load_workbook('scanreport.xlsx')

hitdetails = (str(hostname), str(host), str(port), str(keyword), str(banner))
wb = Workbook()
ws = wb.active
start_row = 1
start_column = 1

for searchresult in hitdetails:
    ws.cell(row=start_row, column=start_column).value = searchresult
    start_column += 1
start_row += 1

wb.save("scanreport.xlsx")
```

**Result:**
[image: Only writes last result]
How can I fix this?

Comment: Easier to use `ws.append()` than using your own counter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@skjoshi, you sir just fixed my problem with overwriting:

[write into excel file without overwriting old content with openpyxl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45412115/write-into-excel-file-without-overwriting-old-content-with-openpyxl) (this page)

Because I am already loading an existing file with an existing sheet, I was also creating a new worksheet, which will overwrite the old one in which I lose my data everytime.

In this case I removed the `ws = wb.active` and it worked!